# Zend Framework 2 navigation active class with params

Tags: php, url, zend-framework, menu, navigation

Hi I have create a route like this

```
'webb' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/oferta/[:url1[/:url2][/:url3][/:url4]]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'webb',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
```

So my route is looking for paremeters url1 url2 etc

I have created navigation like this (just one item to show)

```
'page-3' => array(
         'label' => 'example',
         'route'      => 'webb',
         'controller' => 'index',
         'params'     => array('url1' => aa', 'url2' => bb', 'url3' => 'cc'),
    )
```

and when I am rendering it using zend navigation helper everything is working fine despite that the current class of item is not changing to active? Any ideas? could it be done this way or when I am passing params zend navigation will not change class?

Bur url is bulid fine i get something like this /oferta/aa/bb/cc

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Remove controller key from navigation array and it should work (`'controller' => 'index'` is wrong anyway).

From [zend.navigation.pages.mvc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.navigation.pages.mvc.html#zend-navigation-pages-mvc-example-routes)

> Note that when using the route property in a page, you do not need to specify the default params that the route defines (controller, action, etc.).